When packaging a project into JAR, Is it possible to run a custom function during buildtime?
I'm trying to make a maven project and package into JAR file. I need to create a XML file (custom implemented) when I build the project.
I'm looking for a way to run a function inside the project, before actually executing the JAR file, which means the method needs to be run at the buildtime.
And I avoid making another custom maven-plugin project to be imported to the main project.
Is this really possible?
Running function implemented in the project during buildtime
